# Game theory vs Experimental economics

Tags: game-theory, behavioral-economics

What are the main differences in the methods of game theory and experimental economics? Which method is better suited to analyze strategic behavior?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by strategic behavior.

Answer (score 1):

They're complementary to each other.

With the development of Behavioral Game Theory, canonized in Camerer's 2003 textbook, the current paradigm of game theory [1](http://levine.sscnet.ucla.edu/archive/refs4786969000000001307.pdf) is converging towards making theories about how people play games, and test them, most often with experiments.

[Wither Game Theory, Fudenberg & Levine, 2016](http://levine.sscnet.ucla.edu/archive/refs4786969000000001307.pdf)